# Import value from Terraform module

Tags: terraform, terraform-template-file

I have this skeleton for two Terraform modules I'm building: `api-gateway` and `lambda`. This is the file structure:

```
.
├── modules
│   ├── api-gateway
│   │   ├── main.tf
│   │   ├── outputs.tf
│   │   └── variables.tf
│   └── lambda
│       ├── main.tf
│       ├── outputs.tf
│       ├── policies
│       │   └── lambda-role.json
│       └── variables.tf
├── main.tf
├── provider.tf
├── sandbox-environment.tfvars
└── variables.tf
```

The (excerpt) content of `modules/api-gateway/main.tf` is:

```
resource "aws_api_gateway_integration" "lambda_root" {
  ...
  uri = "${aws_lambda_function.fn_name.invoke_arn}"
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_integration" "lambda" {
  ...
  uri = "${aws_lambda_function.fn_name.invoke_arn}"
}

module "lambda" {
  source = "../lambda"
}
```

The (excerpt) content of `modules/lambda/main.tf` is:

```
resource "aws_lambda_function" "fn_name" {
  filename = "${data.archive_file.fn_name.output_path}"
  ...
  runtime = "java8"
}
```

The problem is I can't read the value `${aws_lambda_function.fn_name.invoke_arn}` in `modules/api-gateway/main.tf`:

```
$ terraform init
Initializing modules...
- module.pipeline

Error: resource 'aws_api_gateway_integration.lambda_root' config: unknown resource 'aws_lambda_function.fn_name' referenced in variable aws_lambda_function.fn_name.invoke_arn



Error: resource 'aws_api_gateway_integration.lambda' config: unknown resource 'aws_lambda_function.fn_name' referenced in variable aws_lambda_function.fn_name.invoke_arn
```

Is there a way to "export" that value from within `modules/api-gateway/main.tf`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need to add an output variable in `modules/lambda/outputs.tf`.

```
output "lambda_invoke_arn" {
   value = "${aws_lambda_function.fn_name.invoke_arn}"
}
```

Then in the `modules/api-gateway/main.tf`, you can reference the output of the lambda module.

```
resource "aws_api_gateway_integration" "lambda" {
  ...
  uri = "${module.lambda.lambda_invoke_arn}"
}
```

Comment: You were right, although, the only way the `api-gateway` module is able to see that value is if I create a module inside of it like this one: `module "lambda" { source = "../lambda" }`. Is that a hack of me trying to make this work, or is it OK that way?

Comment: can you add what `main.tf` looks like? You should have to add new module inside of api-gateway

Comment: I updated the question with what I had to add in `modules/api-gateway/main.tf`. Let me know...

Comment: sorry, I meant the `main.tf` in the root directory